# Can Heroku Redis (or similar Redis add-on) also serve as a message queue?

Tags: heroku, redis, dyno, heroku-redis

I haven't found much documentation on "standalone" Redis VS Heroku Redis, so I'm not quite sure whether the below is feasible for an add-on version.

I'd like to create a scalable architecture suitable for real-time communication between client and server:

- Socket.io running on multiple Node.js instances (web dynos)
- Redis add-on (Heroku Redis) serving as a central in-memory datastore

  - each web dyno using the [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) adapter for comms over a shared bus
- Heroku Redis also serving as a message queue utilizing [Redis Simple Message Queue](https://github.com/smrchy/RSMQ)

  - each worker dyno consuming messages from Heroku Redis message queue

Has anyone had success with an approach similar to the above? Would it be wiser just to use a separate message queue add-on offered by Heroku?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You should direct this question to Heroku's support - it should be doable.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to try and spin up a quick POC, but will followup with Heroku's support if needed.